# WPF/MVVM Load same UserControl multiple times in tab control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, caliburn.micro, tabitem

I'm quite new to WPF/MVVM and have a lot to learn still, but I'm hitting an issue at the moment that i can't seem to find good answers for. Most probably because I'm asking the wrong questions.

What I have:
I have a main form with some buttons which load user controls. One of these user controls contains a TabControl.

This TabControl has a manually populated first Tab, which I've excluded from below snippet, but all other tabs should be populated with another user control, which will load database data depending on its viewmodel constructor.

XAML:

```
             <TabItem Header="Two" 
                     Name="Two" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding LoadedControl}"></ContentControl>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Three" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding LoadedControl}"></ContentControl>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Four" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding LoadedControl}"></ContentControl>
            </TabItem>
```

C#

```
        private DocumentTemplateControlViewModel _loadedControl;

        public DocumentTemplateControlViewModel LoadedControl
        {
            get { return _loadedControl; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _loadedControl)
                    return;

                _loadedControl = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LoadedControl);
            }
        }


        public int SelectedTabIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedTabIndex;
            }
            set
            {

                Task.Run(() => LoadData());
                _selectedTabIndex = value;
                LoadedControl = new DocumentTemplateControlViewModel(Templates, _selectedTabIndex);
             }
```

Now, This works as I intended it to work for Tab Two, but if I add the same line of

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding LoadedControl}">
```

to Tab Three,Four,etc.. (as I've done in the XAML snippet above) it will only work on the last tab that I've added the binding to, and Tab two,three will be blank.

I also tried to achieve the same thing with Caliburn Micro ActivateItem but this means i can also only declare one ActiveItem in my TabControl XAML as well.

TLDR: What is the best way to dynamically show a new user control viewmodel within a tabitem?

Thanks so much

Comment: A specific UI element can only appear once but why are you trying to display the same content in several tabs? There is only one `LoadedControl` property, isn't it?

Comment: Hey mm8,

The User control has a few items on it such as a listbox and a dynamic grid, which is populated by data from a database.

in my case, The tabs are Template choices. Based on the choice, the data that will get populated in the user control will be different, but the actual user control should be the same, just with different data.

There is only one LoadedControl at the moment as I don't know what other way to approach it. I could Create a LoadedControl2,3,4,5 and Bind those to the other tabs, but there must be a cleaner way to achieve that

Comment: So why don't you return an `IEnumerable<DocumentTemplateControlViewModel>` from an `Items` property of the view model and use a `ContentTemplate`? How do you initialize `LoadedControl`?

Comment: Probably because I'm not familiar with the ContentTemplate and couldn't figure out how to apply it in my case. LoadedControl at the moment is only initialized on a tab index change as per C# snippet above

Comment: If I follow what you want to do correctly. I would probably build a usercontrol to encapsulate the UI. Define a viewmodel for that. Associate a datatemplate which is the usercontrol via datatype= to the viewmodel type. Then when you present one of those viewmodels via itemssource you get that as datacontext of the usercontrol. This is a fairly standard viewmodel first pattern. The datatemplate can be in the resources of anything in scope. Application, window, tabcontrol.... whatever suits.

Answer (score 0):

Derive your view model from `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive` and add the `DocumentTemplateControlViewModel` objects that you want to bind to the tabs to the `Items` property:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        Items.Add(new DocumentTemplateControlViewModel { DisplayName = "1" });
        Items.Add(new DocumentTemplateControlViewModel { DisplayName = "2" });
        Items.Add(new DocumentTemplateControlViewModel { DisplayName = "3" });
    }
}
```

`DocumentTemplateControlViewModel` must implement `IScreen` and the easiest way to do this is to derive from `Screen`:

```
public class DocumentTemplateControlViewModel : Screen
{
}
```

In the XAML you could then simply add a `TabControl` with a `ContentTemplate`, e.g.:

```
<TabControl Name="Items">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

You may replace the `TextBlock` with a `UserControl` or any other UI element.

Comment: Hello mm8,

Thanks for that. I tried to get this logic working for a little while but I must confess I didn't get very far. Though I think I might be setting up the Usercontrol datatemplate incorrectly.

Additionally, the first tab of my tabcontrol will look entirely different from the template, is there a good way around that?

Comment: @JoranStoops: Where did you fail with this example? You can just copy and paste it into your solution.